# unwanted situations after creating button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, dynamic

I need to create a button dynamically with javascript. so i wrote these codes in between "script" tags.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var newButton = document.createElement('input');
    newButton.type = 'button';
    newButton.value = 'What's the day today?';
    newButton.id = 'btn1';
    newButton.onclick = myfunction();
    div1.appendChild(newButton);
}
function myfunction() {
    var x = new Date().getDay();
    switch (x) {
        case 0: alert("sunday"); break;
        case 1: alert("monday"); break;
        case 2: alert("tuesday"); break;
        case 3: alert("wednesday"); break;
        case 4: alert("thursday"); break;
        case 5: alert("friday"); break;
        case 6: alert("saturday"); break;

    }
}
```

when the page is loaded, "myfunction()" function is running automatically. after that when i press this button, nothing happens. what's my mistake?

Comment: The color coding in your post shows you the problem.

Comment: This won't run anyways because you didn't escaped the ' in "What's".
for everything else, see @Arun P Johny 's solution.

Comment: Well, you are calling the function in `newButton.onclick = myfunction();`.

Comment: note: switch is not really necessary: use a simple and straight array lookup. e.g. `alert(["Sunday", ..., "Saturday"][x]);`

Comment: thanks for everything. i used Arus's solution and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
newButton.onclick = myfunction;
```

When you do `newButton.onclick = myfunction();` it executes the `myfunction` and then assigns the value returned by it to the `onclick` handler, in this case undefined. What you need to do is to pass the function reference to the `onclick` property

Also I assume the following is a copy paste change

```
newButton.value = 'What's the day today?'; // you need to escape ' with \' or use "What's the day today?"
```